# How do I create an android shortcut to an activity?

Tags: java, android

OK,I'm new at this forum, so don't blame me for putting this in the wrong tags,not putting something in,eg.
I want to learn how to create a shortcut(I did that by Googling) and link it to an activity (In this case, com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity)
I tried doing it, but it only showed me a toast saying "Application not installed" and I'm pretty sure it is.
It would be better if you can display a "complete action with another application" dialog.

Comment: What do you mean by shortcut here? Shortcut on your Android home screen?

Answer (score 2):

If I assumed your question correctly, you mean a button or something within an activity that leads to another activity, that being -- "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity"

if your activity that you want to link to is in another application-- then

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.mine", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity"));
startActivity(intent);
```

if it is within the same application, then

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ComposeMessageActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);


//optional add this to your manifest to finish the current loading activity so 
//as to not keep it in the activity stack
//<activity android:name="yourActivity" android:noHistory="true" ... />
```

*EDIT* If you mean a shortcut on a homescreen, then I would create a tiny application that only has one activity which uses the above method to link to a different application. Then I would drag that application to the home screen, and boom. If there's a better way, then please feel free to correct me

Comment: i think he mean a shortcut on the home screen

Comment: Good answer, but not the right question. This would've been helpful for me yesterday.